# Best approach to parallelize BW and FW algorithms

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I have implemented the BW and FW algorithms to solve L and U triangular matrix.
The algorithm that I implement run very fast in a serial way, but I can not figure out if this is the best method to parallelize it.
I think that I have taken into account every possible data race (on alpha), am I right?

```
void solveInverse (double **U, double **L, double **P, int rw, int cw) {
    double **inverseA = allocateMatrix(rw,cw);
    double* x = allocateArray(rw);
    double* y = allocateArray(rw);
    
    double alpha;
    
    //int i, j, t;
    
    // Iterate along the column , so at each iteration we generate a column of the inverse matrix
    for (int j = 0; j < rw; j++) {
        
        // Lower triangular solve Ly=P
        y[0] = P[0][j];
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:alpha)
        for (int i = 1; i < rw; i++) {
            alpha = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t <= i-1; t++)
                alpha += L[i][t] * y[t];
            y[i] = P[i][j] - alpha;
        }

        // Upper triangular solve Ux=P
        x[rw-1] = y[rw-1] / U[rw-1][rw-1];
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:alpha)
        for (int i = rw-2; (i < rw) && (i >= 0); i--) {
            alpha = 0;
            
            for (int t = i+1; t < rw; t++)
                alpha += U[i][t]*x[t];
            x[i] = (y[i] - alpha) / U[i][i];
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rw; i++)
            inverseA[i][j] = x[i];  
        }
    freeMemory(inverseA,rw);
    free(x);
    free(y);
}
```

---

After a private discussion with the user dreamcrash, we have come to the solution proposed in his comments, creating a couple of vector `x` and `y` for each thread that will work indipendently on a single column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a discussion with the OP on the comments (that were removed afterwards), **we both came to the conclusion that:**

You do not need to *reduce* the `alpha` variable, because outside the first `parallel region` it is initialized again to zero. Instead, make the `alpha` variable *private*.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 1; i < rw; i++) {
    double alpha = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t <= i-1; t++)
        alpha += L[i][t] * y[t];
    y[i] = P[i][j] - alpha;
}
```

and the same applies to the second `parallel region` as well.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = rw-2; (i < rw) && (i >= 0); i--) {
    double alpha = 0;
    for (int t = i+1; t < rw; t++)
        alpha += U[i][t]*x[t];
    x[i] = (y[i] - alpha) / U[i][i];
}
```

Instead of having one `parallel region` *per*  `j` iteration. You can extract the `parallel region` to encapsulate the entire outermost loop, and use `#pragma omp for` instead of `#pragma omp parallel for`. Notwithstanding, although with this approach we reduced the number of `parallel regions` created from `rw` to only 1, the speedup achieved with this optimization should not be that significant, because an efficient OpenMP implementation will use a pool of threads, where the threads are initialized on the first `parallel region` but reused on the next `parallel regions`. Consequently, saving on the overhead of creating and destroying threads.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   for (int j = 0; j < rw; j++) 
   {
        y[0] = P[0][j];
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 1; i < rw; i++) {
            double alpha = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t <= i-1; t++)
               alpha += L[i][t] * y[t];
            y[i] = P[i][j] - alpha;
        }

        x[rw-1] = y[rw-1] / U[rw-1][rw-1];
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = rw-2; (i < rw) && (i >= 0); i--) {
             double alpha = 0;
        
             for (int t = i+1; t < rw; t++)
                 alpha += U[i][t]*x[t];
             x[i] = (y[i] - alpha) / U[i][i];
        }
    
        #pragma omp for
        for (int i = 0; i < rw; i++)
           inverseA[i][j] = x[i];  
    }
}
```

I have shown you this code transformations so that you could see some potential *tricks* that you can use on other future parallelizations. Unfortunately, as it is that parallelization will not work.

Why?

Let us look at the first loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 1; i < rw; i++) {
    double alpha = 0;
    for (int t = 0; t <= i-1; t++)
        alpha += L[i][t] * y[t];
    y[i] = P[i][j] - alpha;
}
```

there is a dependency between `y[t]` being read in `alpha += L[i][t] * y[t];` and `y[i]` being written in `y[i] = P[i][j] - alpha;`.

So what you can do instead is to parallelize the outermost loop (*i.e.,* assign each column to the threads) and create separate `x` and `y` arrays for each thread so that there is no *race-conditions* during the updates/reads of those arrays.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{   
     double* x = allocateArray(rw);
     double* y = allocateArray(rw);

    #pragma omp for
    for (int j = 0; j < rw; j++) 
    {
        y[0] = P[0][j];
        for (int i = 1; i < rw; i++) {
            double alpha = 0;
            for (int t = 0; t <= i-1; t++)
               alpha += L[i][t] * y[t];
            y[i] = P[i][j] - alpha;
        }
        x[rw-1] = y[rw-1] / U[rw-1][rw-1];

        for (int i = rw-2; i >= 0; i--) {
             double alpha = 0;
             for (int t = i+1; t < rw; t++)
                 alpha += U[i][t]*x[t];
             x[i] = (y[i] - alpha) / U[i][i];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rw; i++)
           inverseA[i][j] = x[i];  
     }

    free(x);
    free(y);
}
```